# Default docstring format for Python in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

In `IntelliJ IDEA -> Preferences`, under `Tools / Python Integrated Tools` you can set, on a per-module basis, your `Docstring format`. (This allows you to choose between reStructuredText, NumPy, EpyText, Google and plain formats.) Is there a way to set a default for the entire IDE? Or at least for the entire project? Or are you constrained to setting it on each module individually?

Answer (score 3):

There is an open request for this, please vote:

- [PY-20243](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20243) " Default Settings" dialog in Idea does not have "Python Integrated Tools" settings

Comment: Done! Thanks for the link to that.